# Manipulate du's output to get a custom printout

Tags: directory, disk-usage, sort

I typically run the command below to check size on each directory.

```
du -sBM /* | sort -nr | head -n20
```

However, specifying a block size of "M" here will give everything a value in "M". The problem with that is once you get below 1M everything reports back as 1M. So this solution is not optimal for me. If I run the command below:

```
du -sh /* | sort -nr | head -n20
```

I get the output I really want (block sizes in G,M,and K) but its all out of order. For instance:

```
618M    /var
387M    /lib
336M    /home
260K    /root
184K    /dev
102M    /boot
32M /etc
32K /tmp
27M /lib64
24K /opt
16K /lost+found
14M /sbin
8.0K    /mnt
7.4M    /bin
4.0K    /srv
4.0K    /net
4.0K    /misc
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /cgroup
2.2G    /usr
```

I get M's on top of G's and K's on top of M's and so on. I want my output to look like this:

```
2.2G    /usr
618M    /var
387M    /lib
336M    /home
102M    /boot
32M     /etc
27M     /lib64
14M     /sbin
260K    /root
184K    /dev
32K     /tmp
24K     /opt
16K     /lost+found
8.0K    /mnt
7.4M    /bin
4.0K    /srv
4.0K    /net
4.0K    /misc
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /cgroup
```

Is there a one-liner here that would do what I want or would a script be a better solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sort`'s `-h` option instead of `-n`:

```
du -sh /* | sort -hr | head -n20
```